# Weblogic 12.2.1.3 webjar-locator not working

Tags: spring-mvc, weblogic, webjars

I have a multi module Maven Spring project and can't get webjars-locator-weblogic to work with it.

The webjars are reachable and the mapping is declared as:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
```

However, if i try to use the version agnostic link, the response is always 404. Have already tried with both webjar-locator and webjar-locator-weblogic dependencies with no success.

Have been using this exact same configuration with other servers and never had any issues.

What am i missing?

Comment: I don't think we've done any testing with this setup so it is possible there is a bug.  Perhaps file an issue at: https://github.com/webjars/webjars-locator-weblogic

Comment: Done. Thanks for the support. If tou need any more info/details, let me know